# How do I separate these rows from the second column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a large table that, after some filtering for duplicate, looks like the below and I need the "TAGS" to be in the column adjacent to the "SERIALS". I've tried a Pivot Table but it does not separate them into their own columns, just consolidates under the headers from the column 1. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Simple to do in Power Query, if that is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data is in `A1:B8`.

In `E1` put `=OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)*2,0)`

In `F1` put `=OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)*2,1)`

In `G1` put `=OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)*2+1,1)`

And drag all 3 downwards.

Idea : Use `Offset()` locate required cell, `ROW()` guide the range "shift".

Please share if it works/not..

Comment: This worked flawlessly. You are a wizard. Thanks!